# grails with ajax modal dialog form - data elements duplicating

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails, modal-dialog

Using Grails 2.3.5.
I have a form in a gsp page. Within this page, I have a button to open a modal dialog box with its own form. Using ajax, user click the button, a call to a controller method to render a gsp template with the form in a dialog box. The user submit the form to a controller to process the data. All is good here. The problem begins when the same dialog form is opened and submitted more than once. The posted data elements on the form are multiplied and are appended to the previously submitted data. So if I have one input field, inputField01, the first time the form is posted, it is serialized as &inputField01=test01. The second time the form is posted, it is serialized as &inputField01=test01&inputField01=test02 and so on...
Any one have seen this or similar problem, any fix or an alternative?

Here is the button and script for the dialog:

```
<input type="button" value="Add Sales Account" id="addSalesAccountsButton" class="btn btn-primary">


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {  

var Win = {};

Win.Popup = function (a_title, a_url, a_forward, a_EmployeeId) {

    var properties = {
        autoOpen: false,
        title: a_title,
        modal: true,
        width: 625,
        height: 'auto',
        resizable: false,
        position: ['center', 15]
    };
    var element = $('<div/>').dialog( properties );

    this.addProperty = function(property, value) {
    element.dialog('option', property, value);
    };

    this.changeTheme = function(){      
    ($(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").addClass("ui-state-error"))            
    }

        this.show = function(event) {
            $('#saSpinner').css({'display' : 'inline'});
            if ( ((a_EmployeeId == null) || (a_EmployeeId.length == 0 ))){
            element.dialog('open').load(a_url, {id: event.currentTarget.id, forward: a_forward},
            function() {
            $('#saSpinner').css({'display' : 'none'})
             $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").addClass("ui-state-note")          
            }
             );
            }else{
            element.dialog('open').load(a_url, {id: event.currentTarget.id, employeeHrId: a_EmployeeId , forward: a_forward},
          function() {
            $('#saSpinner').css({'display' : 'none'})
            $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").addClass("ui-state-note")       
          }
        );
            }

        };
    };


    Win.AddSalesAccounts = {
    openDialog: function(event) {
        var strEmployeeHrId = document.getElementById('employeeHrId').value;

        var AddAccount = new Win.Popup('Sales Account Form', '/RateClassChange/remote/showSalesAccountForm', $('.referer').attr('id'), strEmployeeHrId);
        AddAccount.addProperty('buttons', {
            "Add Sales Account": 
        function() {    
        $('#saSpinner').css({'display' : 'block'})

        $.post("/RateClassChange/remote/addSalesAccount", $("#salesAccountForm").serialize(),
                function(responsePage) {
                $("#addSalesAccountResults").html(responsePage);
                }
        );

                $(this).dialog("close");
                $('#saSpinner').css({'display' : 'none'});
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
             $(this).dialog("close");
             $(this).html("");
            }
        });
        AddAccount.show(event);
    },

    init: function() {
        $("#addSalesAccountsButton").click( this.openDialog );
    }
    };

    Win.AddSalesAccounts.init();  

});
</script>
```

This is the gsp template with the form rendered in the dialog box:

```
<table>
      <tr>
          <td>
         <label for="commissionPlan" style="padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px">Commission Plans:</label>
             <g:select class="dropDown form-control " style="width:auto; height:30px;padding:0px 0px 0px 10px" name="commissionPlan"  from="${session.commissionPlansList}" optionValue="planNameDisplay" optionKey="planName" value="${params.commissionPlan}" noSelection="['':'-- Select Plan --']" />

         </td>
         <td>
             <label for="commissionRate" style="padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px">Commission Rate:</label>
             <g:textField class="form-control" style="width:125px;padding:0px 3px 0px 5px;height:30px;" name="commissionRate" value="${params?.commissionRate}" /><label>%</label>

         </td>
       </tr>
</table>

</form>
```

Comment: Can you please post your HTML  + JS code ? Its difficult to identify the problem without any code.

Comment: Thanks Prakash for looking into this. I updated my question with some code.